# Not able to call external resources through kubernetes ingress

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to configure ingress resources in kubernetes, I want to know if I can access external resources via kuberntes(Example, I installed kibana in a virtual machine and I want to access through kubernetes ingress as below)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: "/"
          backend:
            serviceName: service1
            servicePort: 1000
        - path: "/test"
          backend:
            serviceName: service2.test
            servicePort: 2000
        - path: "/kibana"
          backend:
            serviceName: <ip-address>
            servicePort: 9092

Any suggested is this the right way of calling external resources(or) we cannot initiate a call as it is outside of kubernetes...

I am trying to call as test.com/kibana

Please suggest.
```

Answer (score 0):

For external resources you should create `Endpoints` object.

This is explained with [Services without selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors)

> Services most commonly abstract access to Kubernetes Pods, but they can also abstract other kinds of backends. For example:
>
> - You want to have an external database cluster in production, but in your test environment you use your own databases.
> - You want to point your Service to a Service in a different  [Namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces)  or on another cluster.
> - You are migrating a workload to Kubernetes. Whilst evaluating the approach, you run only a proportion of your backends in Kubernetes.
>
> In any of these scenarios you can define a Service  *without*  a Pod selector. For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
```

> Because this Service has no selector, the corresponding Endpoint object is  *not*  created automatically. You can manually map the Service to the network address and port where it’s running, by adding an Endpoint object manually:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: my-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.0.2.42
    ports:
      - port: 9376
```

So once you add the `Endpoint` setup a `Service` for it, you will be able to use is inside `Ingress`.